# -bash: !: event not found

Tags: command-line, mac

I want to remove all folder and files except a folder named docs.

```
echo !(docs)
```

but I got `-bash: !: event not found`?

I'm using mac default terminal.

Comment: Well Mac OS isn't Ubuntu and Mac OS doesn't use Bash AFAIK.

Comment: Feel free to ask your question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/ . @Zacharee1 my Mac OS X machine does indeed use Bash as its shell: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`

Comment: @Zacharee1 so `cd`, `mkdir` is consider apple's command?

Comment: @EuniceChia I don't think those are exclusive to Bash.

Comment: @NickWeinberg well that's interesting. I looked it up and saw a bunch of articles on how to get Mac to use Bash, so I figured it wasn't the default shell.

Comment: By default, Mac OSX comes with the ancient bash version 3.2.  Extra work is required to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

1. `!(doc)` is an *extended glob* and `extglob` is turned off.  If your bash supports `extglob`, you can turn it on with:

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   ```
2. *History expansion* is turned on.  To turn if off, run

   ```
   set -H
   ```

   History expansion causes surprising things to happen when `!` are used.  If you do not use history expansion, you can avoid surprises by turning it off.

#### Example

Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
docs  file1  file2
```

Now, let's turn extglob *off* and history *on* and run your command:

```
$ shopt -u extglob; set -H
$ echo !(docs)
bash: !: event not found
```

This is exactly the error message that you reported.  Thus, this appears to be your situation.

Now, let's keep extglob *off* and turn history expansion *off*:

```
$ shopt -u extglob; set +H
$ echo !(docs)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This error is different from the one you reported.  This is not your situation.

Lastly, let's run your command with extglob *on*.  For completeness, we will try history expansion in both settings:

```
$ shopt -s extglob; set +H
$ echo !(docs)
file1 file2
$ shopt -s extglob; set -H
$ echo !(docs)
file1 file2
```

Both of these work.  Thus, as long as your shell supports extglob and has it turned on, your command should work.